# race conditions when using update statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, race-condition

I have an update statement using hibernate, that increments the count by a value. The statement I'm using is this

```
UPDATE_STMT="UPDATE STATS.PROCESSED SET COUNT = COUNT + ? WHERE ID = ?"
```

I'm preparing the statement and executing it in this way. All the below code is under a `transaction/commit/rollback` pattern.

```
update = session.connection().prepareStatement(UPDATE_STMT);
update.setLong(1, data.getCounter());
update.setLong(2, data.TransId());
update.execute();
```

But it looks like there are race conditions and the DB isn't being updated properly. The update is being performed from multiple application servers.I would like to know if updating using the statement above is a safe way to do it or are there any better ways of handling this situation.

Comment: What do you mean, "not updated properly"?  That statement will add 1 to the specified column: [you won't have a race condition like you might get in a procedural language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example), because SQL (DB2 at least) _temporarily_ locks rows during updates.  The best thing to do is to figure out why there are multiple servers calling this statement - that's a problem on it's own.  Otherwise, maybe value-based optimistic locking will work.

Comment: by "not updated properly" I meant the counts aren't as expected which indicates some sort of race condition while updating or selecting for update. Multiple servers run the same processing code and update counts from their end, hence the `COUNT = COUNT + ?`. Thanks for the pointer on optimistic locking, is there any standard way to perform such updates with out race conditions.

Comment: Your biggest problem is **YOU ARE RUNNING THE SAME STATEMENT ON MULTIPLE SERVERS AND NOT EXPECTING THE RESULTS YOU ARE GETTING**.  Depending on the reason you're doing this, you may be causing the db server to do more work than it needs to.  If you _do_ do optimistic locking, you probably need to raise exceptions in Java - which means the _app_ server would be doing extra work.  This statement is fine on its own - there's probably some problem in your app if this is an issue; for example, what is `data.getCounter()` coming from?  If you're running the update multiple times due to that...